# Unity2DでuGUI(Imageゲームオブジェクト)の幅をワールド座標で取得したい

Tags: unity2d

Unity2DでuGUI(Imageゲームオブジェクト)の幅(Width)をワールド座標で取得したくて本ソースコードを書きましたが、
期待しない値が入っているため困っています。

期待した値：
Canvas上のImageゲームオブジェクトの幅がワールド座標に変換された(0.9, 0.0, 0.0)くらいの値。

結果：Image のVector3(変数名：oneSquareForward)に(105.3, 0.0, 90.0)が入っていた。

私の行った手順は本ソースコードの通りです。

本ソースコード:

```
///<summary>
///プレーヤー1をスプライトの大きさぶん右へ表示
///用途：プレーヤーの指に隠れてキャラクターが見えなくなることを防ぐために使う
///</summary>
public static Vector3 oneSquareForward = new Vector3(2.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

/// <summary>
/// 機能：oneSquareForwardにワールド座標でPlayerGameObject()の幅を設定する。
/// 
/// 引数：なし
/// 
/// 戻り値：なし
/// 
/// 備考：参考サイト：
/// ①【Unity】GameObjectの幅と高さを取得・変更する方法（RectTransform）：https://techno-monkey.hateblo.jp/entry/2018/05/12/150845
/// ②RectTransformからワールド座標に変換する方法：http://alien-program.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/06/164258
/// </summary>
private void Set_oneSquareForward()
{
    // ワールド座標の幅を取得したいimageゲームオブジェクト(Player)を取得する
    GameObject player = GameObject.Find("Player");

    // PlayerのRectTransformを取得する
    RectTransform playerRectTransform = (RectTransform)player.transform;

    // Playerの幅(Width)を取得するローカル変数
    Vector3 playerWidth = Vector3.zero;

    // Playerの幅を取得する
    playerWidth = new Vector3(player.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // UI座標からスクリーン座標に変換 
    Vector2 screenPos = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(Camera.main, playerWidth);

    // ワールド座標を保持するローカル変数
    Vector3 result = Vector3.zero;

    // スクリーン座標→ワールド座標に変換
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(playerRectTransform, screenPos, Camera.main, out result);

    // oneSquareForwardに変換結果を入れる
    oneSquareForward = result;
}

// Set_oneSquareForwardの呼び出し元はAwake
private void Awake()
{
    Set_oneSquareForward();
}
```

Unityのインスペクター上の設定：
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

デバッグ中の変数の値：
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

私は、本ソースコードで、Imageゲームオブジェクトの幅をワールド座標に変換できると思いました。
なぜなら、参考サイトには、以下のように書かれており、その通りにコーディングしたつもりだからです。
1 RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPointで、UIの座標をスクリーン座標に変換する。
2 1で取得したスクリーン座標を、RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangleを使ってワールド座標に変換(result)する。

ただ、直接sizeDeltaをワールド座標に変換する参考サイトではないので、私のソースコードのどこかが間違っているのかもしれませんが、どこが間違っているかわかりませんでした。

また、参考サイトを元にして書いた、UI座標からスクリーン座標に変換するコードですが、
UI座標とは何かということが検索してもよくわかりませんでした。

他のサイトや英語のサイトも見てみましたが、参考にできそうなサイトがなく困っています。

どうすればUnity2DでuGUIのImageゲームオブジェクトの幅をワールド座標で取得できるのか教えて頂けるとありがたいです。
どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
解決した後のコードを投稿させて頂きます。

```
// 呼び出し元：
private void Awake()
{
    Set_oneSquareForward();
}

// 呼び出し先：
///<summary>
///プレーヤー1をスプライトの大きさぶん右へ表示
///用途：プレーヤーの指に隠れてキャラクターが見えなくなることを防ぐために使う
///</summary>
public static Vector3 oneSquareForward = new Vector3(2.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

/// <summary>
/// 機能：oneSquareForwardにワールド座標でPlayerGameObject()の幅を設定する。
///
/// 引数：なし
///
/// 戻り値：なし
///
/// 備考：参考サイト：
/// ①＜ワールド座標とローカル座標の変換＞：https://dkrevel.com/unity-explain/space/
/// ②【Unity】GameObjectの幅と高さを取得・変更する方法（RectTransform）：https://techno-monkey.hateblo.jp/entry/2018/05/12/150845
/// ③RectTransformからワールド座標に変換する方法：http://alien-program.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/06/164258
/// </summary>
private void Set_oneSquareForward()
{
    // ワールド座標の幅を取得したいimageゲームオブジェクト(Player)を取得する
    GameObject player = GameObject.Find("Player");

    // PlayerのRectTransformを取得する
    RectTransform playerRectTransform = (RectTransform)player.transform;

    // Playerの幅(Width)を取得するローカル変数
    Vector3 playerWidth = Vector3.zero;

    // Playerの幅を取得する
    playerWidth = new Vector3(player.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // 親のゲームオブジェクト(Canvas)
    GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");

    // ローカル座標からワールド座標に変換
    Vector3 world_playerWidth = canvas.transform.TransformPoint(playerWidth);
    // ↑の変換する際にCanvasのワールド座標のZ座標に変換しているので、z座標を他の処理の値と合わせるために0.0fを代入
    world_playerWidth = new Vector3(world_playerWidth.x, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    // oneSquareForwardに変換結果を入れる
    oneSquareForward = world_playerWidth;
}
```